# Joint Quadratic variation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X,Y$ be square integrable Right continuous martingales. If $Z$ is the total variation of $\langle X,Y\rangle$, how can I show that 
$$Z \leq \frac{1}{2}[\langle X\rangle + \langle Y\rangle].$$ I have tried using the properties:

$\langle aX+bY,Z\rangle = a\langle X,Z\rangle + b\langle Y,Z\rangle$

$\langle X,Y\rangle = \langle Y,X\rangle$

$|\langle X,Y\rangle|^2 \leq \langle X\rangle\langle Y\rangle$

But nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the inequality $\langle X-Y\rangle\geqslant0$.